# What is the meaning of card in the sentence "I'm a wild card."?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of card in this sentence:

> I'm a wild card.

Can you show other examples which describe the people as a card?

Comment: Other playing card examples include **an ace up one's sleeve** (a hidden asset), one's **strong suit** (their expertise), and to **show one's hand** (to reveal something hidden). English is full of card game idioms.

Comment: More generally, an **ace** is an expert in one's field.

Comment: Also I think people can occasionally be called *trump cards*.

Comment: Also, **card** all on its own, such as "You're such a card!" Means the person thinks you are funny.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you needed to search *wild card*, not just *card*, to understand the meaning.

In addition to the answer provided, here are a few more "simple" definitions from Merriam-Webster:

> [wild card](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wild%20card)
>   : a person or thing that could affect a situation in a way that cannot be predicted
>   : an unknown or unpredictable factor
>   *sports* : a player or team chosen to fill a place in a competition after the regularly qualified players or teams have all been decided

So *I'm a wild card* could also mean that this person is *unpredictable*.

Again, depending on the context, some possibly related words are *adventurous*, *spontaneous*, and *unstable*, just to name a few.

It's also possible that the person is filling a *wild card* position, as some players or teams do in sports.

Comment: Now that you've been dealt into this discussion and the chips are down on the table, it's your time to call Glorfindel's bluff and play your hand, complete with your trump card. To call a spade a spade, you hold all the aces in this one. +1

Answer (score 4):

In some card games, a [wild card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_card_(card_games)) is a card that can be anything you like. Similarly, a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) can be used to represent any other character.

That's the origin of the expression; when used for persons it probably means someone who can do everything you like, or someone who can be used for many tasks. We need more context to determine exactly what's meant.

Comment: Describing someone as a "wild card" can also mean they're unpredictable.  But as you say, we really would need more context.

Comment: Note that "wild card" and "wildcard" are the same thing and both correct - "wildcard" as one word is likely newer.  There is a common   occurrence in English that multiple words get combined.  Sometimes there is a hyphen, sometimes a space, sometimes neither.  For example, there once was e-mail, now just email or Email.